# WP_nav_menu fallback not working

Tags: menus

I just realized the fallback doesn't work for my project when a custom menu doesn't exist.  I can't figure out what I am missing.  Here is the code that displays the nav menu:

```
$menu = wp_nav_menu(
   array(
      'menu_class' => 'reset sf-menu',
      'container_id'=>'nav',
      'echo'=>0
   )
);

$menu = str_replace("\n", "", $menu);
$menu = str_replace("\r", "", $menu);
$menu = str_replace("\t", "", $menu);
echo $menu;
```

here is the test site: http://brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/amplify/styles/charcoal/

Comment: What exactly does it return? Check with `var_dump()` on `$menu`.

Comment: wp_nav_menu falls back to the wp_page_menu function. Do you have any pages defined?

Comment: I have the default "About" page defined as the only page, I also tried adding two more pages and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

You've not added a `fallback_cb` key to the argument array. You also need to add a `theme_location` key:

```
php start $menu = wp_nav_menu(
   array(
      'menu_class' => 'reset sf-menu',
      'container_id'=>'nav',
      'echo'=>0,
      'fallback_cb' => 'mytheme_fallback_function' // ADD ME!!!
      'theme_location' => `location_name` // ADD ME, AS DEFINED IN register_nav_menu()
   )
);

$menu = str_replace("\n", "", $menu);
$menu = str_replace("\r", "", $menu);
$menu = str_replace("\t", "", $menu);
echo $menu;
php end
```

Alternately, you could wrap your code in an `if ( has_nav_menu( 'location_name' ) )` conditional:

```
if ( has_nav_menu( 'location_name' ) ) {
    echo $menu;
} else {
    // Do something else, like wp_list_pages() or wp_page_menu()
}
```

Comment: Actually, it's "fallback_cb", not "fallback". Also, it defaults to the wp_page_menu function, so you shouldn't need to define it except for non-default cases.

Comment: Is WPSE experiencing a bug or did something mess up your end, because i'm seeing `php start` and `php end` in your above code, which should naturally be `<?php` and `?>`..

Comment: yeah that is just a bug in the wpse displaying things so i replaced the php tags here